# colorbox content wrong size

Tags: media, javascript

I created a page in Drupal 7 using two pictures and would like to display them with color box. The link: http://quaaoutlodge.com/content/salmon-run now two problems: There for some reasons seem to be 4 pictures in the group, two of which are totally out of size and get stretched to 650 x 800 px but I just want them to show in their original size. How can I get rid of the stretched ones?

Comment: How are you setup your colorbox and have you fixed any image style for your images?

Comment: "I created a page" - node? custom module's page? Also remember that "link-only" questions are not OK here. Can you imagine anyone provide good answer if the link is no longer valid? If no, your question is not a valid one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ur html `rel="gallery-all"` is available which means you allow to load all the images in the galery or page, for resolving your issue (for single load) remove this rel attribute.

The rel attribute specifies the relationship between the current document and the linked document.In colorbox "gallery-all" means it will load all images to colorbox. For eg here load 4 images, perhaps select "single" load the main image

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hello. I'm sorry to say that but your answer is unreadable for me, I can' understand what you meant. Could you try to clear language used, rewrite it for clarity?

Comment: Please use the small "edit" link under your answer :)

Comment: @madhurjya Thanks for your reply. I now removed the rel  attribute from the tag and now the images are just unrelated to each other (no more arrows ion the bottom) but the "stretching" still occurs...

Comment: @cerr your original image quality is poor. `http://www.quaaoutlodge.com/sites/default/files/styles/gallery-cblarge/public/300px-AdamsRiverWide.JPG`

Comment: @madhurjya and your does not open ;p "Error generating image."

Comment: http://www.quaaoutlodge.com/sites/default/files/styles/gallery-cblarge/public/300px-AdamsRiverWide.JPG  no space after 300px-

Answer (score 0):

I checked your page/colorbox, the colorbox-size seems to be correct, the box has the size of the shown image.
So i suggest that you check the image-style settings of the "gallery-cblarge"-imagestyle.